# how to reset textPlacement.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want it so that when the button is pressed, it resets the value of `textPlacement.innerHTML` to an empty string, ensuring there is no text. The issue is that currently, when I press the button, it adds the new value to the right of the previous values. Please keep in mind that I want to retain the HTML text "Background Color: ".

```js
let textPlacement = document.getElementById("insert-colour");
let simpBackgroundColour = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;

textPlacement.innerHTML += "";

if (simpBackgroundColour === 1) {
  document.body.style.background = "#eb1e17";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Red";
} else if (simpBackgroundColour === 2) {
  document.body.style.background = "#2390de";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Blue";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "#d9d923";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Yellow";
}
```

```html
<h class="background-colour-box" id="insert-colour">Background Colour : </h>

<div class="button">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: A typo?  `+= ""` doesn't really do anything meaningful.  It appends *nothing* to whatever value is already there.  If you want to *set* the value to `""` then maybe you meant to use `=` instead of `+=`?

Comment: Just set the text to what you want it to be; i.e., `textPlacement.innerHTML = "Background Colour : Blue";`.

Comment: `textPlacement.innerHTML = ""`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not just set "Background Color: color" on each if?

```
let textPlacement = document.getElementById("insert-colour");
let simpBackgroundColour = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;

if (simpBackgroundColour === 1) {
  document.body.style.background = "#eb1e17";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Background Colour :Red";
} else if (simpBackgroundColour === 2) {
  document.body.style.background = "#2390de";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Background Colour : Blue";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "#d9d923";
  textPlacement.innerHTML += "Background Colour : Yellow";
}
<h class="background-colour-box" id="insert-colour">Background Colour : </h>

<div class="button">Click Me</div>
```

This will keep Background Color on whatever statement matches, and will rewrite the innterHTML each time.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to reset the `textPlacement.innerHTML` with `"Background Colour : "`.
When you use + with the string, it will do concat(keep adding the other string).

```js
//uncomment the below code if you want to keep `h1` tag background red
//document.getElementById('insert-colour').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    let textPlacement = document.getElementById("insert-colour");
    let simpBackgroundColour = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;

    textPlacement.innerHTML = "Background Colour : ";

    if (simpBackgroundColour === 1) {
        document.body.style.background = "#eb1e17";
        textPlacement.innerHTML += "Red";
    } else if (simpBackgroundColour === 2) {
        document.body.style.background = "#2390de";
        textPlacement.innerHTML += "Blue";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "#d9d923";
        textPlacement.innerHTML += "Yellow";
    }
});
```

```html
<h1 class="background-colour-box" id="insert-colour">Background Colour : </h1>

<button class="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)s. This way, you can divide your text into two parts. The first span is for the fixed text, and the second span is for the variable color name. You can refer to this separately and modify the text with [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). If possible, avoid using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) unless absolutely necessary.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button.body-color-change");
const span = document.querySelector("span.body-color-name");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const randomColor = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;
    
    switch(randomColor) {
      case 1:
        document.body.style.background = "#eb1e17";
        span.innerText = "Red";
        break;
      case 2:
        document.body.style.background = "#2390de";
        span.innerText = "Blue";
        break;
      case 3:
        document.body.style.background = "#d9d923";
        span.innerText = "Yellow";
        break;
    }
});
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Background Color: </span>
  <span class="body-color-name"></span>
</h1>

<button class="body-color-change">Click Me</button>
```